# Which is correct? "In as greater detail as possible" or "In as great a detail as possible"

Tags: grammar, sentence

The question title really says it all. I have Googled the subject but not found the answer!

Comment: Second version. Just google _"In as greater detail as possible” OR “In as great a detail as possible”_

Comment: You're better to say "with as much detail as possible".

Answer (score 3):

You can never use *as greater as* because *greater* is a comparative. It is always *greater than* (or just *greater* if the comparison subject is omitted or mentioned before).

Therefore, the right construction is the second one: *as great as* (or, in this case, *as great a detail as*).

Answer (score 1):

"In as greater detail as possible" is definitely wrong, as @Gorpik explained, but "In as great a detail as possible" also sounds slightly clumsy to me. I'd go with "in as much detail as possible" or maybe "with the greatest possible detail".